# How to change the value of activate_url in django allauth?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am using allauth and after registration the user receives an email asking them to click a link to verify their email address. I would like to change the value of this link.

I would like to change it from

```
http://localhost:8001/account/confirm-email/hy72ozw8b1cexuw2dsx4wwrmgzbmnyxx4clswh67tcvgyovg/
```

to

```
http://localhost:8001/index.html#/verifyEmail/hy72ozw8b1cexuw2dsx4wwrmgzbmnyxx4clswh67tcvgyovg/
```

How can I do this? I see that `activate_url` value is being used in [email_confirmation_text.txt](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/80087605a6e5d49fbed6dc7e923bb0d79b143dbc/allauth/templates/account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't really have to override `allauth`'s `urls.py` in order to achieve this, all you need to do is specify your version of url **after** including `allauth`'s urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from allauth.account.views import confirm_email

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.account.urls')),
    url(r'^index.html#/verifyEmail/(?P<key>\w+)/$', confirm_email,
        name="account_confirm_email"),
    # but I would recommend changing that url:
    url(r'^verify-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$', confirm_email,
        name="account_confirm_email"),
    ...
)
```

Here is a nice article about URLS: [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI)

Comment: Glad you added this. I thought of this and found myself second-guessing whether it would work, but didn't have time to test it properly.

Comment: There one more issue here, anything after '#' in a URL won't be send to the server by a browser. So the above solution won't work until the '#' is removed from the URL. @birdy, Do you really need the '#'? If not, just remove it and everything would work perfectly.

Comment: @DebanshuKundu, very good point, anything after `#` in url will not get passed to the server, unlesss it is escape to `%23`. Moreover, there is no reason on having `index.html` or any `.html`in django's urls at all.

Comment: @AlexeyKuleshevich Thanks for the answer. However, I'm getting an error `name 'confirm_email' is not defined` In my `urls.py` I have the following `url(r'^account/', include('allauth.urls'))` Here is my entire `urls.py` https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b6505cefa5307f71ccab

Comment: That's because you are missing an import: `from allauth.account.views import confirm_email`.

Comment: Thanks, very useful, but I need to change the domain, because I want to redirect user to my front-end(web), then my front-end call my API and get the proper data

Comment: @MoeFar if you need to change a domain in some way, take a look at django-hosts, it's a very nice app.

Answer (score 3):

I have not used django-allauth or incorporated it into one of my projects, but just poking around in their source code tells me the following:

The [send method](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/models.py#L118) just does a basic `urlresolvers.reverse` call, which means it's constructing the URL from `account/urls.py` as defined [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/urls.py#L22).

As such, you have three options:

1. Overwrite their `urls.py` which you will have to repeat each time you update the package (yuck).
2. Raise an issue on their GitHub and see if they will add this as a configuration option rather than "hard-coding" it which they have done.
3. Try to subclass their `EmailConfirmation` model, overriding their send method with something more appropriate for your project, and see if you can get it to use yours instead of theirs (no idea if this is workable or not).